# Write coffeescript cake file in literate coffee

Tags: coffeescript, literate-programming

I would like to write a Cakefile in litcoffee (as in Cakefile.litcoffee), is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that cake [does not do any literate checking](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/master/lib/coffee-script/cake.js#L53) when it finds and runs your Cakefile. You can of course add this behaviour if you are so inclined.

I would still try running `cake -l` and adding a `#!/usr/bin/env coffee -l` shebang to your file, you never know, right?

Barring the above, for what it's worth, I've had success using Grunt with litcoffee using [this incantation](https://github.com/Cheezmeister/luchenlabs/blob/master/Gruntfile.coffee).